# PyQt4: How to make file dialog pop out and stay?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, qfiledialog

I'm using Python3 and trying to be familiar with PyQt4. `File dialog` is good to import data in PyQt. I would like to use File dialog and choose single or multiple file/s. So I wondering the how to make pop-out file dialog stay after I click several files in it.

Comment: some feedback ?

Answer (score 0):

To select several files you must use `QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames`

**Example 1:**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    filenames = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()
    print(filenames)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Example 2:**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    filenames = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(None,
        "Select one or more files to open",
        QtCore.QDir.homePath(),
        "Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)")
    print(filenames)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```